# Extracting all block attributes with ezdxf

Tags: python, pandas, autocad, dxf, ezdxf

I want to extract all the block attributes and put them on a df. Some of the attributes are default, and some are custom attributes:
[Block attributes to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dem1K.png)

```
import ezdxf as ez
import pandas as pd
doc = ez.readfile("data.dxf")

# Get the modelspace
msp = doc.modelspace()

# Initialize df with all block attributes
entities_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate over all entities in the modelspace and append to df
for entity in msp:
    to_dict = pd.DataFrame([entity.attribs()])
    entities = pd.concat([entities, to_dict])
    print(blocks_df)
```

.attribs() is not returning every attribute. I'm getting "handle, layer, flags, text, style, name..." but not the attributes I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Per your included screen clip, you want to collect from each insert: its position (x,y,z), its scale in x, y, z, and the value for each attribute attached to that instance of the INSERT.

Collecting Position and Scale vs collecting the Insert's CAD attribute values are different processes.

```py
# given an Entity `e` of type INSERT

x, y, z = e.dxf.insert  # position
scale_x = e.dxf.xscale
scale_y = e.dxf.yscale
scale_y = e.dxf.zscale

# the CAD Attributes are read like this:

MyAttrib_1 = e.get_attrib_text("MyAttrib_1)

# an so on
```

This is not intended to be a complete function, there are 100's of ways to assemble that data into a DataFrame, but these are the calls that will get the needed data.

[EZDXF Documentation - INSERTs](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/blocks/insert.html) contains methods you can use to check if the CAD Attributes exist, how to control the default return string when the CAD Attribute is not present, and other tools.